# Save state to localstorage

Tags: reactjs

I'm new to react, I have a search bar, when I enter something, it automatically updates the results, but I want to be able to navigate away from the page and when I come back, I want it to be persisted. The search should be retained until manually cleared by the user.

This is my code so far:

```
    import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";
import { useOnClickOutside } from "../../hooks";
import useDebounce from "../../hooks/useDebounce";
import { ISearchProps } from "./search.props";
import { SearchWrapper } from "./Search.style";

const Search: React.FC<ISearchProps> = ({onChange, placeholder = "Search by..."}) => {
    
    const [value, setValue] = useState<string>("");
    const debouncedValue = useDebounce(value, 500);
    const [expandInput, setExpandInput] = useState(false);
    const ref = useRef(null);
    const [input, setInput] = useState<HTMLInputElement | null>();

    useEffect(()=>{
        onChange(debouncedValue);
        window.localStorage.setItem('SAVE_SEARCH', JSON.stringify(value));
    }, [debouncedValue]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        const data = window.localStorage.getItem('SAVE_SEARCH');
        if (data !== null) 
        setValue(JSON.parse(data))
    }, [setValue]);

    useEffect(()=>{
        expandInput && input?.focus();
    }, [expandInput]);

    const searchHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
       setValue(e.target.value);
    }
    
    useOnClickOutside(ref, () => value === "" && setExpandInput(false));
    

    return(
        <SearchWrapper expandInput={expandInput} ref={ref}>
            <input ref={inputEl => setInput(inputEl)} type="text" onChange={(e) => searchHandler(e)} value={value} placeholder={placeholder} />
            { (expandInput && (value.length > 0)) && <i className="ico-Exit" onClick={()=> setValue("")} ></i>}
            <button className="search-button" onClick={() => setExpandInput(true)}>
                <i className="ico-Search"></i>
            </button>
        </SearchWrapper>
    )
}

export default Search;
```

I can see this in dev tools > Storage, it's updating as I type: [image]

Not sure what I'm missing, please help!

Comment: your component is unmounted wen you go to another page on the same tab, which means the state is lost

Comment: any ideas on how to fix it, please, I'm so stuck in this @NumanIjaz

Comment: You have to store your search string somewhere. Do you have state management (e.g. redux)? Put it there or use browser storage.

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize your state by getting the value of local storage. `useState hook` accept a function as a parameter.

```
  const [value, setValue] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem('SAVE_SEARCH'))
```

Now, when your component would render, it will get the value that is on local storage and assign to your state.

But, it would be easier if you would use `React Context` to manage `global values`.

https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context

Comment: and when do you put SAVE_SEARCH into local storage?

Comment: Inside on `searchHandler` function.

Comment: This would be:

`const searchHandler = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      window.localStorage.setItem('SAVE_SEARCH', JSON.stringify(value));
      setValue(e.target.value);
}`



Would be good!

Comment: This is the error i get :

Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'.  TS2345

     8 |     
     9 |     const [value, setValue] = useState(window.localStorage.getItem('SAVE_SEARCH'))
  > 10 |     const debouncedValue = useDebounce(value, 500);
       |                                        ^
    11 |     const [expandInput, setExpandInput] = useState(false);
    12 |     const ref = useRef(null);
    13 |     const [input, setInput] = useState<HTMLInputElement | null>();

Comment: But, yo be honest you could remove your first `useEffect (where you was getting local storage data)` and use the second one with the `debouncedValue` to `set` the value of `SAVE_SEARCH`. This would work better because you would call this just when the `debouncedValue` changes.

Comment: @MGmgmgmg update your `useState` type to

`string | null`

Like this: 



`const [value, setValue] = useState<string | null>(window.localStorage.getItem('SAVE_SEARCH'))
`

Comment: but as son as I update it, i get the same error: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string'. :(((  @JoãoSantos

Comment: you can remove this type assign because typescript will automatically assign a type for your use state. Can you do it?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/qcayYCsp
can you PLEASE take a look, this is almost working, but when i type "test" in dev tools > storage i only see "tes"

Comment: @JoãoSantos please

Comment: hm, when I type 3 letters, it cuts one, e.g when I type "lea" I can se "le"

Comment: is it not the delay of debounced value?

Comment: i really don't get it, it's always -1 on string

Comment: I saw it, i'm trying to fix on codesandbox. Just wait a minute

Comment: I got it. you was setting the previous value in searchHandler function.

you was doing it:

`window.localStorage.setItem('SAVE_SEARCH', JSON.stringify(value));`

but should be:

`window.localStorage.setItem('SAVE_SEARCH', JSON.stringify(e.target.value));`

Comment: @MGmgmgmg check it:

https://pastebin.com/RrNesSZW

Comment: @MGmgmgmg ur welcome! Can you upvote my answer? and let your question as answered? i would be glad!! thank you so much

Comment: i think i did it :D if there's anything else i can do, like send an award, let me know <3 thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Write yourself a custom react hook:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function usePersistantState<T>(
   key: string,
   initialValue: T
): [T, (value: T) => void] {
   const [state, setInternalState] = useState<T>(initialValue);

   useEffect(() => {
       const value = localStorage.getItem(key);

       if (!value) return;

       setInternalState(JSON.parse(value));
   }, [key]);

   const setState = (value: T) => {
       localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
       setInternalState(value);
   };

   return [state, setState];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, set **localStorage** with the same value which you are storing in to **State**.

```
  const saveCartData = (cartData) => {
    setCartItemsList(cartData);
    localStorage.setItem("cartItems", JSON.stringify(cartData));
  };
```

Second while initializing your state get the localStorage value

```
const cartInitialValue = () => {
  return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cartItems")) || [];
};
```

Apply local storage value to initial value of state.

```
  const [cartItemsList, setCartItemsList] = useState(cartInitialValue);
```